# How to parse json string recived from pyserial?

Tags: python, json, pyserial

I use the pyserial library to get data from an Arduino. I use the fallowing code:

```
import serial
import JSON

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
while True:
    print(ser.readline())
```

When I run the program I get: `b'{"x":"-1","y":"0"}\r\n'` but I expect `{"x":"-1","y":"0"}`.

I know that I can remove \r\n by using stipe() method on ser,redline(). I also noticed that b' is from bytes.

When I try load string to json by command `data = json.load(ser.readline().strip())` I get an error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'`

How can I parse the string to json format?

Comment: Are you using python2.x?

Comment: `json.load()` is for reading data from a file.  Use `json.loads()` to read from an existing string.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-python-string

Comment: @Roshi I agree that the merits of the question is duplicate but the context (which is important) isn't even similar.

Comment: I use python 3.5.

Comment: json.loads() returns: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 0: invalid start byte"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `your_line.decode('utf-8')` to decode your line